# how to pass custom types as parameter to a compiled cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am writing a Powershell CmdLet in C#. I have a parameter that I would like to take an array of custom types. How would I make Powershell aware of the fact that a custom type is required?

I'll elaborate with an example so you can get an idea of my setup, starting with `Tuples`.

The C# bit:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "FooValues")]
public class GetFooValues : PSCmdlet
{
    private IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string>> relatedColumns;
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string>> RelatedColumns
    {
        get { return relatedColumns; }
        set { relatedColumns = value; }
    }
    
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var retval = Helper.GetValues(relatedColumns);
        WriteObject(retval, false)
    }
}
```

Where `Helper` is just a 'proxy' to a 3rd party assembly that I'll call `MyDll`:

```
static class Helper
{
    List<List<string>> GetValues(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string> cols)
    {
        using (var x = new MyDll.Foo())
        {
            foreach (var c in cols)
            {
                x.DoSomething(c.Item1, c.Item2, c.Item3)
            }
            return x.GetSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

This could work, I can create `Tuples` in Powershell and pass them to the `Get-FooValues` command. However, obviously the order of strings in the `Tuple` matters, so what I would like to do instead is use a custom type and use proper property values to pass to `MyDll`.

Let's assume a `RelatedColumn` type:

```
class RelatedColumn
{
public string Connection { get; set; }
public string ToCategory { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The parameter portion would become something like:

```
private IEnumerable<RelatedColumn> relatedColumns;
[Parameter(Position = 0)]
public IEnumerable<RelatedColumn> RelatedColumns
{
    get { return relatedColumns; }
    set { relatedColumns = value; }
}
```

This is where I start to have questions. How do I make Powershell aware of the fact that type `RelatedColumn` is required? How could I tell it what it even looks like? Would I have to recreate the type it in Powershell?

Disclaimer: I am new to Powershell. It is quite puzzling to me so far.

Comment: How do I make Powershell aware of the fact that type RelatedColumn is required? What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to point this out to the user or what exactly should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace Tuple with your custom class. As long as it's in the same DLL file as the Cmdlet it should work with no problems, since PowerShell allows creation of any class from any loaded binary module.

This article describes importing custom classes from modules in detail: https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules

Comment: Okay I think I am getting the idea. Correct me if I'm wrong: before I can use the command, I have to import the module. That's just a dll. So does that mean I can use it like I would when I reference a dll using Add-Type? In other words, Import-Module can be thought of as adding a reference in a C# project?

Comment: I think it's equivalent to using `Assembly.Load()` in your C# code. Also, if your DLL is dependent on some other DLLs, that are not loaded by PowerShell by default, you need to specify those in the manifest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.

Comment: OK - I have found this article: https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules, which claims if you want your custom classes imported you need to import the module with `Using` rather that `Import-Module`. I di not realise there was a difference, sorry.

Comment: That article is very helpful, tx

Comment: Oh I think your comment on the need for a manifest only applies to modules created with Powershell, not in a compiled module. I have a ton of references to other dlls in the module dll, it would be weird to have to tell powershell it needs them, right? Perhaps I misunderstand your remark.

Comment: You might be right. What I wrote is just my interpretation of the documentation. The modules I created only used classes from DLLs that PowerShell loads anyway, so I had no occasion to test this.

Comment: I just realized that in my case I can simply Add-Type the library that is holding the compiled module. But that just feels very weird. `Using module` works just fine.